# Unsure of how to use duration_cast as a macro function

Tags: c++

I'm not sure how to use duration_cast and its syntax. Can duration_cast convert just between the members in std:chrono? Can it be used to convert an integer or float to a time point? 
I'm also working on a project and I'm trying to find the duration between the current time and the initial time using duration but I keep getting the error `No matching function for call to 'duration_cast'`

```
#define time std::chrono::high_resolution_clock
#define duration(x, y) std::chrono::duration_cast<std::milli>(x-y)
    time::time_point c_time = time::now();
    time::time_point start;

        auto dur = duration(c_time, start);
```

Comment: Don't use a macro here.  Write a function instead.  It is a a lot safer and easier to get working.  Also, don't use macros for type aliases.  Use a using declaration instead, `#define time std::chrono::high_resolution_clock` -> `using time = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;` as preprocessor directives are quite greedy.

Comment: I'm kind of new to this so sorry if this sounds trivial but what's the difference between using a preprocessor directive and ```using``` or ```typedef``` in this scenario

Comment: The preprocessor is a text replacement engine.  It scans through the code text and in this case will replace every occurance of `time` with `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock`.  This could be really bad though if you have say, `int time = 42;` in your code as now it becomes `int std::chrono::high_resolution_clock = 42;` which will not compile.  If you use a `typedef` or using declaration this can't happen as type aliases don't overwrite variable names.

Comment: thank you, that makes sense. do you also know how to use duration_cast to convert from one form to another? I'm getting different information from different sites and I'm still confused on the syntax of it

Comment: Here's a 1h `<chrono>` video tutorial to get you started: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P32hvk8b13M  It has information on `duration_cast`, and a lot of other information that will help you use this library properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should almost never be a reason to touch the preprocessor with modern c++. It obfuscates your code and makes it fragile (apart from `#include` obviously).

Your code can be rewritten as:

```
using time = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;
auto duration = [](auto x, auto y) { return std::chrono::duration_cast<std::milli>(x-y); };
time::time_point c_time = time::now();
time::time_point start;
auto dur = duration(c_time, start);
```

The problem with your code is that [`std::milli`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/ratio/ratio) is a `ratio` not a `duration`. You are looking for [`std::chrono::milliseconds`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration) instead. The code now compiles:

```
using time = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;
auto duration = [](auto x, auto y) { return std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(x-y); };
time::time_point c_time = time::now();
time::time_point start;
auto dur = duration(c_time, start);
```

Comment: I am unfamiliar with the syntax and format of the second line. What do the square brackets signify? And is ```duration``` a function or a variable, because I have not seen the equal sign being used like this before

Comment: It's a lambda, you could just add easily declare it as a function, i just used a lambda to be closer to your original code